# template metaprgramming for generating item list for #pragma omp task depend

Tags: dependencies, task, openmp, generator, template-meta-programming

For taskification purpose, OpenMP proposes  #pragma omp task depend  such as:

```
#pragma omp task depend ( dependence-type: locator-list [: iterators-definition])
```

Can template metaprogramming help to generate list of depends() clause of different sizes for #pragma omp task depend?

I need a way to generate (dependence-type: locator-list [: iterators-definition]) at compile time based on user information.

If possible, could you please advice me on how to achieve it?

Comment: You can't generate preprocessor tokens using template-meta-programming. Maybe describe your actual problem to see if there is a different possibility.

Answer (score 0):

pragma directives are preprocessing tokens, so they can't be generated with template-meta-programming.

Using the `_Pragma()` operator though, you can generate a pragma directive from a macro expansion. Have a look at [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122041/1387346) which uses X-Macros (in C) to generate depend clauses with any number of dependencies.